# Simple Question of Application of Vector on a Cube

Tags: geometry

Question:

Given that $E$ is the intersection of diagonals $BA$ and $OD$; $M$ is the intersection of $CE$ and $OD'$.

Denote $\overrightarrow{OM}$ in terms of $\overrightarrow{OA}$, $\overrightarrow{OB}$ and $\overrightarrow{OC}$.

[image]

I even have problem to visualize if $CE$ and $OD'$ intersects each other. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those two lines must intersect because they both lie in the plane $ODD'$.

Comment: Thanks, this question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

hint:

$\overrightarrow{OM}$ is on $\overrightarrow{OD'}$,you can write  $\overrightarrow{OD'}$ with 
$\overrightarrow{OA}$, $\overrightarrow{OB}$,$\overrightarrow{OC}$

if you can calculate $OM=?OD'$, the problem is solved.

what is the relation between $CE,OD'$? $(OD=\sqrt{2}CO)$

Comment: Thanks for your drawing and explanation first. I am able to find $OE$ and $OC$. I think the next step is to find $OM$ by means of $OE$ and $OC$. But I am not sure if $\angle CMO$ is $90^{\circ}$ or not. May you give me some more hints? Thanks so much.

Comment: CODD' is A4 size. so $\triangle COE $ similar $ODD'$.

Comment: Is the next step to prove $\bigtriangleup OME$ is similart to $\bigtriangleup COE$ and thereby find the value of $OM$?

(By the way, the reasons to prove $\bigtriangleup COE$ similar to $\bigtriangleup ODD'$ is because their sides are proportional?)

Comment: no, it is not necessary to prove OME, COE similar(they do). when you prove COE similar ODD'(you already know it), $\angle CMO$ is $90^{\circ}$ already.(becasue both triangles are right.)

Comment: I am able to prove $\triangle COE$ and $\triangle ODD'$ because 3 pairs of their corresponding sides are proportional. However, I cannot persuade myself that $\angle CMO = 90^{\circ}$. (Thank you for your patience to guide me.)

Comment: look at $\triangle OME,\angle MEO+\angle MOE=\angle MEO+? $,you prove two triangles similar, so $\angle MOE= ?$, the angle in triangle COE. now you should get it.

Comment: That means should I claim that $\triangle OME$ and $\triangle COE$ are similar to each other?

Comment: sorry, I used wrong words. I mean that you already proved two triangles (COE and ODD') are similar ,so you get $\angle MOE= ?(ie,\angle COE)$. that is all.

Comment: I think $\angle MOE = \angle OCE$, right?

Comment: ya,you are right. a typo. :P